# When using window.onbeforeunload on page refresh, how do we check which button they pressed

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

The following code works nicely:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        return 'Wait a moment';
        };
});
```

However, how do I detect if the user, in default dialogue, chose "Refresh" or "Don't Refresh"?

If they opt to refresh, I *don't* want to display my modal as it will auto close and appear broken - I only want the modal to fire if they opt to remain on the page/not refresh.

Comment: If they opt to refresh, the page will be reloaded, so your script stops running.

Comment: It doesn't though, that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check below snippet. Using setTimeout function you will be able to achieve your requirement.

```js
var vals=0;
function displayMsg() {
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
window.onbeforeunload = function evens(evt) {
  var message = 'Wait a moment.';
  if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
    evt = window.event;
  }       
  timedCount();
  vals++;
  if (evt) {
    evt.returnValue = message ;
    return message ;
  }
  trace(evt);
} 

function timedCount()
{
  t=setTimeout("timedCount()",100);
  if(vals>0)
  {
    displayMsg();
    clearTimeout(t);
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not work... The page has to be refreshed twice for the modal to appear and when you opt to refresh the modal still appears. Thank you.